Как добавить \x00 в print в Си, чтобы запись не прерывалась
Читаю книгу "Искусство эксплойта" Эриксона, и появилась проблема на моменте, когда нужно заменить адрес возврата. Для этого нужно выполнить подобную команду
$(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x00\x00"x30')
Как видите, после \x00 запись сразу прерывается, хотя остальные адреса записаны в виде "0x00007fffffffdc38"
Строка, которая отвечает за копирование argv[1] - strcpy(searchstring, argv[1])

Насколько я понимаю, вам надо искать что-то вроде perl write binary constants. Не знаю толком perl, но возможно этот ответ будет полезен. Если же проблема еще и в том, что вы пытаетесь подсунуть в атакуемой программе эти данные в strcpy, то ничего не выйдет, на первом же нуле копирование прекратится. Ищите в качестве жертвы какой-нибудь вызов memcpy/memmove

Большое спасибо, вы действительно помогли. Строчку strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]) надо заменить на memcpy(searchstring, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])), а запись в perl изменить на что то вроде$(perl -e 'for ($x=0; $x<40; $x++){ print pack("q", 0xf343324255)}') (количество повторений и адрес, конечно же, под себя подстраивать). И вроде бы все хорошо, но тут я вспомнил, что в строке с memcpy мы берем длину argv[1], которая так же является *char и прерывается на 00, ее тоже меняем на memcpy(searchstring, argv[1], 100). Тогда все работает, хотя это и костыли, но для обучения пока пойдет
